# img inside div should fill width or height

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div which contains an image

```
<div class="logo-wrapper">
    <img src="img/logo.jpg">
</div>
```

and following CSS:

```
.logo-wrapper {
   width: 197px;
   height: 78px;
   position: relative; 
}

img {
   bottom: 0;
   display: block;
   height: 100%; /* this */
   width: 100%; /* or this, depending on image ratio */
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0
}
```

The image inside `.logo-wrapper` is generated dynamically and each has a different ratio. What I intend to do, is to fill the `img` whether in the `height` or `width` of its parent depending on the dimensions of the image. I could do that with an background image instead, but I don't want to have trouble with old IE's. So does anyone have a solution that the `img` takes whether height or width, depending on its ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is bigger than `.logo-wrapper`, you can use

```
img {
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

If not, it won't grow, but this way you won't have a blurred image.

Comment: thanks, that seem to work! can you tell me is it working for down to IE 8? Also it seems that centering with `margin: 0 auto;` won't work anymore?

Comment: @supersize `max-height` and `max-width` are supported by IE7+. And to center it you also need `left: 0; right: 0`.

Comment: thank you, but do you have an idea, why this cracks my `margin: auto;`?

Comment: remove `position: absolute` from the `img`

Comment: @lloiser but then I would loose the possibility to vertically align the image? so with the CSS above it would center, vertical AND horizontal! Any advice?

Comment: @lloiser thank you, it does! Don't know what was the issue, anyway!